# How to create multiple hosts on docker-swarm with docker desktop

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I used to create multiple node on docker-swarm with virtual toolbox. So each node corresponded to creating a new virtual machine. This way each virtual machine had separate IP.

Now, docker toolbox is deprecated. I am trying to learn about docker-swarm and want to create multiple nodes/hosts.

How can i create multiple node/hosts with docker desktop for windows?

Comment: That depends on your container needs. Do you need to run Windows containers, Linux containers, or both?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't spend time trying to configure multi-node Swarm with only Docker Desktop. Just use a Linux manager node + Windows worker nodes (which can each run Docker Desktop without complicating the Swarm management set up). Full steps listed here for creating an example Swarm cluster in this format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69058087/7991646

Answer (score -1):

What (i think) you are looking for is actually a well defined .yaml file whit all your services and ports where they should listen.

Check the example here, it should clarify a bit how you should create the hosts in docker-swarm https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/

In this other file, you can see a more realistic .yaml with `replicas` value set. It regulates how many hosts you should have per service
https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app/blob/master/docker-stack.yml

Comment: To create multiple nodes, one needs multiple hosts. With Virtual box, i can create multiple machine(like docker-machine create nodexyz) but docker desktop has only one underlying instance. That is the problem.

Comment: Now I got it, apologies

Comment: Can't you run simply multiple instances of an os from an image (ubuntu for example)?